# jquery window.resizeTo in Slow Motion

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, transition, window.open

I want to resize a window in slow motion mode but the following code doesn't work and I have no idea what to do:

```
var myWindow;

function resize() {
   var windowsHeight = jQuery(window).height();
   var windowsWidth = jQuery(window).width();
   var DivX = windowsWidth - 320;
   var DivY = windowsHeight - 480;
}

myWindow = window.open("/", "", "width=320, height=480"); 
myWindow.resizeTo(windowsHeight, windowsWidth),1000;
myWindow.focus();
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720195/control-speed-of-browser-window-resize-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

In this example you can see the animation effect. Just customize it as you wish.

The trick is to use a custom animation with [`jquery.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```js
function pop(){
  var win = window.open("", "Title", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=780, height=200, top=0, left=0");
  win.document.body.innerHTML = "HTML";

  $({foo:0}).animate({foo:100}, {
    step: function(val) {
      win.resizeTo(val * 5, val * 5);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="pop()">Open</button>
```

**Note:** You can see the effect within the snippet for a security reason. You can see the effect in the fiddle(jsbin) I created:

http://jsbin.com/fojuva

**Note 2:** I checked this code in `Google Chrome` and `Mozila Firefox` The latest versions.