# Control speed of browser window resize in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to control the Window resize speed in JS.
For eg:

```
window.resizeTo( 350,800 );
```

The resizing happens almost instantly. Is it possible to change the speed or apply any other animation.

Thanks!

Comment: That's not possible as it is not controlled by JavaScript.

Comment: If you really need to do this, you'll have to manage the animation yourself (i.e. successively set intermediate sizes). But that sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760620/jquery-window-resizeto-in-slow-motion

Comment: @PraveenKumar did you just post a link to another question, which has a link to this question, which will have a link to the other question, which will ....

Comment: @Tarekis Are you looping? `:P`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yeah, i think you made a endless loop `:P`

Comment: Please see my answer is the similar question (Thanks to @PraveenKumar for the reference) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760620/jquery-window-resizeto-in-slow-motion/34721943